# I am trying to read data from a file which is tab delimited but it is giving me errors

Tags: c

I am writing a program which takes data that the user inputs and writes it into a file. Then the data must be output from the file. My issue is that whenever I try to output the data I am given outputs like this "40�z". The first line is a header which I also must output and I have tried outputting it with fgets and printf.

Here is the code.

EDIT: I still had my file open in write mode while trying to read from it. After fixing that I can print the values I need but only in the terminal. If I try to use it anywhere else i get a core dumped error

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//struct declaration
typedef struct employee_data {
    char lastName[20];
    char id[11];
    double grossPay;
    double taxes;
    double netPay;
}employeeData;
//function declarations

void writeEmpFile(employeeData data[], FILE* outFile);
void readEmptFile();

int main(){
    //variable definitions
    employeeData data[5];
    FILE* outFile;
    
    //create file empstat.txt
    outFile = fopen("empstat.txt", "w");
    fprintf(outFile, "NAME\tIDNUM\tGROSS\tTAXES\tNET\n");
    writeEmpFile(data, outFile);
    printf("\n");
    readEmptFile();
    return(0);
}


//function definitions

void writeEmpFile(employeeData data[], FILE* outFile){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
            printf("Enter Last Name (no spaces): ");
            scanf("%19s", data[i].lastName);
            if ((strcmp(data[i].lastName, "EXIT")) == 0){
                break;
            }
            printf("Enter ID Number: ");
            scanf("%19s", data[i].id);
            printf("Enter Gross Pay: ");
            scanf("%lf", &data[i].grossPay);
            printf("Enter Taxes: ");
            scanf("%lf", &data[i].taxes);
            data[i].netPay = data[i].grossPay - data[i].taxes;
            
            
            fprintf(outFile, "%s\t%s\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", data[i].lastName, data[i].id, data[i].grossPay, data[i].taxes, data[i].netPay);
            fclose(outFile);
        }
}

void readEmptFile(){
    FILE* outFile;
    outFile = fopen("empstat.txt", "r");
    //temp variables
    char header[100];
    char h1[6];
    char h2[6];
    char h3[6];
    char h4[6];
    char h5[6];
    double d1;
    double d2;
    double d3;
    
    fgets(header, 10000, outFile);
    printf("%s", header);
    
    fscanf(outFile, "%s%s%lf%lf%lf", h1, h2, &d1, &d2, &d3);
    printf("%s\t %s\t %lf\t %lf\t %lf\n", h1, h2, d1, d2, d3);
    
    //fscanf(outFile, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", h1, h2, h3, h4, h5);
    //printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", h1, h2, h3, h4, h5);
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: That looks like a buffer overflow or failed NUL termination. These buffers look *exceptionally* tiny, which can be a huge risk. I'd suggest using a read buffer size of at least `1024` bytes and carving that up using something like `strtok()` into pieces you can `strdup()` into your structures that have plain `char*` pointers instead of `char[n]` fixed-size buffers.

Comment: Right @tadman, I suggest `scanf("%19s", data[i].lastName);` and similarly for `id`.

Comment: You should also think about creating `NULL` terminated arrays you can pass into functions like `writeEmpFile` instead of *assuming* there will be precisely 5 entries, or consider using a linked-list type structure so you can keep appending as you read indefinitely.

Comment: @pmg At the absolute least, yes!

Comment: When reading from file, the commented-out code is trying to read strings into smaller buffers than they came from: `char h1[6];` etc.

Comment: @tadman could you explain how ```strtok()``` works. I have looked it up but I do not get it

Comment: I found the major issue but now I have a core dumped error. I edited the main post. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're reading something like CSV, you can split on `'\t'` and then you have the "tokens" to parse over. If you're just writing to a file it's not relevant.

Comment: Tip: Use a debugger and step through your code. If you don't know how, now's the time to learn.

Comment: OT: regarding the prototype: `void readEmptFile();`  Since the function takes no parameters, the prototype should be: `void readEmptFile( void );`  Note the 'void' between the parens.

Comment: OT:  the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 5, 6, 11, 20, 100.  suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding: `fgets(header, 10000, outFile);`  the length of the array: `header` is 100, NOT 10000.  The result is the possibility of overflowing the input buffer: `header[]`.  The result is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Much better to use the definition of `header[]` via: `fgets(header, sizeof( header ), outFile);`

Comment: OT: regarding: `outFile = fopen("empstat.txt", "w");`  this call can fail.  So should always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful: (==NULL) then call `perror( "fopen to read the new file failed" );  then cleanup,  then call: `exit( eXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: in function: `writeEmpFile()`  inside the `for()` loop, is the statement:  `fclose( outFile );`  After that statement the file is not accessible.  Therefore, all following iterations of the loop will fail.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fprintf(outFile, "%s\t%s\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", data[i].lastName, data[i].id, data[i].grossPay, data[i].taxes,  data[i].netPay);` always honor the right column (usually column 72 or 80) so the document is easily printable.  suggest starting a new line after each comma that separates the parameters

Comment: OT:  for robust code, check the returned value from each of these I/O statements: ( scanf(), fprintf(), fopen(), fgets() )  as such statement can easily fail.  so test for success immediately and if failed, call `perror()` to output your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: the function: `readEmptFile()` only reads the 'header' line and 1 data line.  Suggest the call to `fscanf()` returned value be used to control a `while()` loop so all the data lines are read and echoed to the terminal

Comment: OT: the data passed to the terminal in function: `readEmptFile()` 'may' result in the columns of data not being aligned on the terminal.